WordPress Plugin - Settings API
I'm in the process of creating an all-in-one WordPress plugin, to be called FlexiPress, to streamline WordPress site management. It will effectively replace a multitude of small, specialized plugins. Features should cover a wide range, from performance enhancement to lightweight security and customization. It acts as a Swiss army knife to manage various administrative workflows and aspects of the site.
However, it has been pointed out to me that my plugin contains a major CSRF flaw, as I don't use the Settings API for plugins. This leads me to save options without any security checks (nonce, role...). So I quickly consulted the WordPress developer documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/plugins/settings/custom-settings-page/
But I still don't see how to adapt my code to use the Settings API.
Here's the .ZIP of my plugin: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OHufCxD-jmezd2b8JQbNxIeMIVT7shmz/view?usp=drive_link
And the code of one of my files containing the feature calls:
<?php
// File : admin/general-settings.php

// Include feature files
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/../includes/disable-automatic-updates-emails/disable-automatic-updates-emails.php');
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/../includes/disable-automatic-updates/disable-automatic-updates.php');
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/../includes/disable-attachment-pages/disable-attachment-pages.php');
require_once(plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . '/../includes/completely-disable-comments/completely-disable-comments.php');

// Checks if features are enabled
$disableautomaticupdatesemails_enabled = get_option('general_enabled_disableautomaticupdatesemails', false);
$disableautomaticupdates_enabled = get_option('general_enabled_disableautomaticupdates', false);
$disableattachmentpages_enabled = get_option('general_enabled_disableattachmentpages', false);
$completelydisablecomments_enabled = get_option('general_enabled_completelydisablecomments', false);

// Form processing during submission
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST' && isset($_POST['save_changes'])) {
    $disableautomaticupdatesemails_enabled = isset($_POST['disableautomaticupdatesemails_enabled']) && $_POST['disableautomaticupdatesemails_enabled'] === 'on';
    $disableautomaticupdates_enabled = isset($_POST['disableautomaticupdates_enabled']) && $_POST['disableautomaticupdates_enabled'] === 'on';
    $disableattachmentpages_enabled = isset($_POST['disableattachmentpages_enabled']) && $_POST['disableattachmentpages_enabled'] === 'on';
    $completelydisablecomments_enabled = isset($_POST['completelydisablecomments_enabled']) && $_POST['completelydisablecomments_enabled'] === 'on';

    // Records toggle switch status
    update_option('general_enabled_disableautomaticupdatesemails', $disableautomaticupdatesemails_enabled);
    update_option('general_enabled_disableautomaticupdates', $disableautomaticupdates_enabled);
    update_option('general_enabled_disableattachmentpages', $disableattachmentpages_enabled);
    update_option('general_enabled_completelydisablecomments', $completelydisablecomments_enabled);
}


// Displays the form and switch toggles
?>
<div class="wrap" id="flexipress-plugin">
    <h2><?php _e('General Settings', 'flexipress'); ?></h2>

    <form method="post" action="">
        <?php
        // Features and their status
        $features = array(
            'disableautomaticupdatesemails' => __('Disable Automatic Updates Emails', 'flexipress'),
            'disableautomaticupdates' => __('Disable Automatic Updates', 'flexipress'),
            'disableattachmentpages' => __('Disable Attachment Pages', 'flexipress'),
            'completelydisablecomments' => __('Completely Disable Comments', 'flexipress'),
            // Add other features as needed
        );

        foreach ($features as $key => $label) :
            $enabled = get_option("general_enabled_$key", false);
        ?>
            <div class="feature-toggle-pair">
                <label class="switch">
                    <input type="checkbox" name="<?php echo $key; ?>_enabled" <?php checked($enabled); ?>>
                    <span class="toggle-slider round"></span>
                </label>
                
                <div class="feature-details">
                    <h3><?php echo $label; ?></h3>
                    <?php if ($key === 'disableautomaticupdatesemails'): ?>
                        <p><?php _e('Stop getting emails about automatic updates on your WordPress site.', 'flexipress'); ?></p> <!-- Function description -->
                    <?php elseif ($key === 'disableautomaticupdates'): ?>
                        <p><?php _e('Completely disable automatic updates on your website.', 'flexipress'); ?></p> <!-- Function description -->
                    <?php elseif ($key === 'disableattachmentpages'): ?>
                        <p><?php _e('Hide the Attachment/Attachments pages on the frontend from all visitors.', 'flexipress'); ?></p> <!-- Function description -->
                    <?php elseif ($key === 'completelydisablecomments'): ?>
                        <p><?php _e('Disable comments for all post types, in the admin and the frontend.', 'flexipress'); ?></p> <!-- Function description -->
                    <?php else: ?>
                        <p>.</p> <!-- Default description -->
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>

            </div>
        <?php endforeach; ?>

        <button type="submit" name="save_changes"><?php _e('Save Changes', 'flexipress'); ?></button>
    </form>
</div>

PS: this is my first plugin so can you help me?
Thanks in advance for your help! Looking forward to hearing from you.
Have a nice day,
Alexis Grolot

One thing I can tell you is to avoid echo as much as possible and prefer esc_html_e and esc_attr_e. You can also echo esc_html, but I like the former because it is easier to grep for stray echo statements. Many times this will feel like overkill, but many of the security issues I’ve seen have been fixed by just adding escaping on render. It is just a good habit to get into.

I would strongly recommend prefixing your option keys with something specific to your plugin. Besides avoiding collisions, for site owners this makes things much easier to debug.

Most of my code these days is client-specific, I don’t write a lot of public plugins, so take this into consideration when I say I don’t feel a need to use the settings API personally. Just make sure to check the current user’s permissions before “doing work” (database updates, FS changes, API calls, etc.), implement nonces, validate and sanitize user input when possible, and escape on render. The security section of the handbook does a great job of explaining this. https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/security/

Super small thing, but with PHP 7 we got the null coalescing operator and the pattern of isset checks with arrays is no longer needed. Your code could be slightly simplified such as this: https://3v4l.org/2XfPd. It is just a personal preference, but I think it is much easier to read.

You should have https://github.com/WordPress/WordPress-Coding-Standards installed in your code IDE.  It will help you improve your code immensely.
